# Prevent swipe in horizontal UICollectionView to swipe in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

iOS 9+ application using Swift 2.2.

I'm using a UIPageViewController having some horizontal UICollectionViews in each page. When scrolling horizontally in my UICollectionView, if I reach the end of my UICollectionView, it changes the page of my UIPageViewController, like if I swiped in my UIPageViewController to change page.

I would like to disable the UIPageViewController swipe when swiping between my UICollectionViewCells, even if I reach the end of my UICollectionView.

It is important that the swipe gesture gets recognized when swiping somewhere else than in my UICollectionView

What would be the better approach to do this?

**UPDATE :** Since iOS 11, I don't have this issue anymore. It was probably a bug that Apple fixed in iOS 11.

Comment: I tried setting self.collectionView.bounces = true and self.collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true, but it's not working. When reaching the end, it stops bouncing and it scrolls in the UIPageViewController instead of bouncing.